# Can I add custom attributes to html elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I am still learning JS and HTML, and I want to know if I can use attributes that don't exist by default, can I add new one from html? can I add new one from JS?

Comment: Yes. Just use HTML5 `data-` attributes. http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: Thanks Terry, but how can I get an element after that where these attributes = something, for example: $("span[data-attribute='my value']") .. I have tried this but it's not working knowing my input has the following: <input type="text" data-attribute='my value' />

Comment: That is because you are selecting a `<span>` element with the attribute of `data-attribute` whose value is `my value`. If you want to match the input, use `$("input[data-attribute='my value']")`. If you want to match the span element after that, use the general or immediate sibling selector: `$("input[data-attribute='my value'] ~ span")` or `$("input[data-attribute='my value'] + span")`.

Comment: oh sorry, they are both input, sorry, the code is like this $("input[data-attribute='my value']")

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
var x = document.getElementById('yourid');
x.setAttribute("TestAttribute", "TestValue");
```

Comment: Hi Alec, can you see my comment above?

Comment: I would defer to the jQuery api:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

The link above has a decent example.  Searching "jQuery get element by attribute" will get you plenty of examples.

Comment: Thanks alec, that method doesn't work for custom attributes

Answer (score 2):

You can set any attributes you want to your html elements.

If you use jQuery see: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

```
$( "#elementID" ).attr( "customAttr", "Anything you want" );
```

Without jQuery

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('elementID');
myElement.setAttribute("customAttr", "Anything you want");
```

Comment: How can I get the element that's using the custom attribute? $("span[data-attribute='my value']"); doesn't work

Comment: Take a look at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) to select with the attribute. Or you could add an ID to your element and select it by id. 

If it doesnt work, I recommend you recreate the problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).